# Automatically changes code through out the application at many places

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text, replace

I need to change the code at many places in my application.

I have two libraries in my application. I have to remove one libraries and have to use components of second library to get the functionality working as it was working previously.

I have found which components to be replaced with which components. Like I have about 30+ classes in first library which will replace second library components.

Is it possible to create any **script** in which i can specify which Text will be replaced and by which text.

**Eg: A to be replaced by B, C by D, E by F, G by H and so on.**

It will be similar to **Find and Replace**, but **not manually**.

The aplication is in C#.

Comment: Sounds like a job for the unix tool `sed`, for perl or for notepad++'s find in files -> replace functionality.

Comment: If you are not good with tools like `sed`, VS find and replace may be an option too as it can replace in many files... Or you can just rename classes with VS (or R#) refactoring and than merge...

Comment: What is wrong with search-and-replace which comes with Visual Studio? You can search through all files at once with [Look in:] "Entire solution".

Comment: Thanks for the reply first...well i can use find and replace in VS but i have a lot of data to be modified like: Class names, their properties, Method names, Enumerations. Doing that manually will take me a bit long time. I was thinking to create a one time script and pass the A(text to be replaced) and B(text to replaced with) stored in some sort of file(excel) and then that script will do the desired work for me at once. After that i will just build my applications and can check for errors. If this sounds to be a non realistic thing then please do tell me.

Comment: This is a really custom job, I would suggest you make your own application if you think this going to be done often, else search and replace.

Comment: @LokeshGarg: Thanks is not needed on this site (everybody wants  help). Furthermore this is not a C#/Visual studio question, it related to text (which hapens to be C#). You solution will probably be a script(like you suggested) which has nothing to do with C# nor visual studio...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will do the needfull.

```
var replaces = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "A", "B" }, { "C", "D" }, {"E","F"} };
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Folder\", "*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var file in files) 
{
  var text = File.ReadAllText(file);

  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> ky in replaces)
  {
       text = text.Replace(ky.Key.ToString(), ky.Value.ToString());
  }

  string [] splittedpath = file.ToString().Split('\\');

  string DirectoryPath = @"C:\Folder\Replaced Files\";
  string FilePath = "";

  for (int i = 0 ; i < splittedpath.Length ; i++)
  {
      if (i != 0 && i != 1 && i != (splittedpath.Length -1))
      {
          DirectoryPath = DirectoryPath + splittedpath[i].ToString() + @"\"; 
      }

       if(i == (splittedpath.Length -1))
       {
           FilePath = DirectoryPath + splittedpath[i].ToString();
       }
  }

  Directory.CreateDirectory(DirectoryPath);
  File.WriteAllText(FilePath, text);
}
```

This will create new files with same directory structure and will not replace the existing files.

Answer (score 0):

Develop a custom tool for doing that.

```
  var replaces = new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"A","B"}, {"C","D"}, ...};
  var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.cs", Recursive);
  foreach (var file in files) {
       var text = File.ReadAllText(file);
       foreach(var replace in replaces) text = text.replace(replace.key, replace.value);
       File.WriteAllText(file);
  }
```

if you want to handle multiline need some effort... but can be acomplished too. And maybe using regexp be a good idea...

Comment: thanks for the start. I have checked for one text value pair and it got replaced successfully(by few modification). Hope that it will help me in achieving what i want to achieve. Will certainly post the entire code soon.